# How to Extend Eslint to work with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm working on a React application and I would like to have a linter set up so that I can see all the warning/errors in the console.

The docs doesn't say much: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/

I have added `EXTEND_ESLINT=true` in my `.env.dev` file and I have created a `.eslintrc.json` file as well, with the following content (taken from the docs):

```
{
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": ["react-app", "shared-config"],
    "rules": {
      "additional-rule": "warn"
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": ["**/*.ts?(x)"],
        "rules": {
          "additional-typescript-only-rule": "warn"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Every rule I try to add won't do anything, I still see no warnings in the console and on top of that if I try to run the linter from the command line:

```
npx eslint ./src
```

I get the following error:

```
ESLint configuration in .eslintrc.json is invalid:
    - Unexpected top-level property "eslintConfig".
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I dont know much about eslint, but I'm willing to bet that `{
  "eslintConfig":` json you have is NOT for a .eslintrc.json file

Comment: That's the code in the documentation, if it's not for a .eslintrc I don't know where to put it!

Comment: I find it really, really frustrating that so much documentation around react and the surrounding tools doesn't actually tell you what file to put their example json in. I feel like it's a huge problem in the node.js tooling community, and probably the dev community at large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either create a `.eslintrc.js` file inside your `src` folder, with this syntax:

```
module.exports = {
    extends: ["react-app", "shared-config"],
    rules: {
      "additional-rule": "warn"
    },
    overrides: [
      {
        "files": ["**/*.ts?(x)"],
        "rules": {
          "additional-typescript-only-rule": "warn"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Or add this to your `package.json` (not a .eslintrc.json file):

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": ["react-app", "shared-config"],
    "rules": {
      "additional-rule": "warn"
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": ["**/*.ts?(x)"],
        "rules": {
          "additional-typescript-only-rule": "warn"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I think we are getting closer, now if I run `npx eslint ./src` I get the following error: "Failed to load config "shared-config" to extend from.
Referenced from: /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Workspace/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/src/.eslintrc.js"

Comment: That's probably because you don't have a shared config you want to extend. Check this: https://eslint.org/docs/1.0.0/developer-guide/shareable-configs

Comment: You'd need to replace 'shared-config' with an actual shared config, if applicable, or replace "additional-rule" with the actual rule you want to add. Same goes for the overrides. The CRA documentation should have made that clearer.

Comment: If all you want is to add a couple of rules to this particular project, a shared config would probably be overkill: just remove that and add rules and overrides as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add plugins rules and configs inside package.json without creating .eslintrc.json and env variables